# Azure - Static Web App - "openIdIssuer" for Tenant produces 404

Tags: azure

I have a Static Web App, it is a simple HTML 5 application. The index page loads successfully, and I would like to add Azure AD authentication, such that a user must login with credentials valid for the tenant the web app is in. I have a staticwebapp.config.json defined as follows:

```
{
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0",
          "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "trailingSlash": "auto",
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ],
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad",
      "statusCode": 302
    }
  }
}
```

`tenantId` is swapped with my actual tenant ID. Under Configuration in Azure Portal, two application settings are defined:

[image]

All other settings and configuration options are default for the Static Web App itself. When accessing `https://my-application.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad`, I receive a 404. When trying to access https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0, I also receive a 404. What steps can I take to determine why the openIdIssuer doesn't appear for my tenant, and how I can allow Azure AD authentication through the webapp without said openIdIssuer?